# how to store the input of radio into datastore

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

```
template_values = {'Answer1':Answer1,
                               'Answer2':Answer2,
                               'Answer3':Answer3,
                               'Answer4':Answer4,
                               'Answer5':Answer5,
                               'QuestionText': QuestionText,
                               'address':address,}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'QuestionPageOthers.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

**HTML**

```
<div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer1}} name="answer" id="answer1"/>{{Answer1}}<span></span></div>
<div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer2}} name="answer" id="answer2"/>{{Answer2}}<span></span></div>
<div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer3}} name="answer" id="answer3"/>{{Answer3}}<span></span></div>
<div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer4}} name="answer" id="answer4"/>{{Answer4}}<span></span></div>
<div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer5}} name="answer" id="answer5"/>{{Answer5}}<span></span></div>
```

I am doing a survey which keeps track of how many users select different options like the codes above, the first part I pass the answers to the Django templates and form the survey using radio buttons, but how can I detect which button is clicked on.  I need to keep track of times that each button has been selected.  However, how can I pass the results back to the Python request handler.  `self.request.get("name")` works for `<input type="text">` but doesn't work for radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your radio buttons are located within the form being POST'ed to your request handler, then you can get the value associated with the selected radio button like this:

```
 select_answer = self.request.get('answer')
```

This quite similar to how you retrieved the value entered for the `name` text field you described in your question - you just replace `name` with the name associated with the radio input elements (i.e., `answer` in this case).

Comment: Thank you for replying me, its working now, but i didnt work for no reasons. btw, why can self.request.get can only catch the **name** field in form but it cant catch the ids? Thank you

Comment: @user624392: that's how HTTP forms work.  The `name` field is the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

template.html

```
<form method="post" action="some-view">
    <div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer1}} name="answer" id="answer1"/>{{Answer1}}<span></span></div>
    <div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer2}} name="answer" id="answer2"/>{{Answer2}}<span></span></div>
    <div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer3}} name="answer" id="answer3"/>{{Answer3}}<span></span></div>
    <div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer4}} name="answer" id="answer4"/>{{Answer4}}<span></span></div>
    <div><input type="RADIO" value={{Answer5}} name="answer" id="answer5"/>{{Answer5}}<span></span></div>
    ...
</form>
```

views.py

```
def some-view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer = request.POST['answer']
        # then update your tally here
        ...
```

Above code should work, but it's not how i could have implemented this. You will find it more efficient to use django forms in this case.